# O que significa: ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

> AreaReservadaComponentComponent.html:2 ERROR Error:
>   ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'hidden: undefined'. Current
>   value: 'hidden: true'.
>       at viewDebugError (core.js:9771)
>       at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:9749)
>       at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9916)
>       at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:13964)
>       at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:13938)
>       at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:14767)
>       at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:14707)
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (AreaReservadaComponentComponent.html:6)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14689)
>       at checkNoChangesView (core.js:13778)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

area-reservada-component.component.html

```
<app-mapa-de-ferias [hidden]="MapaFeriasIsVisible"></app-mapa-de-ferias>
```

=========

MenuComponentComponent.html

```
 <a class="nav-link"  [routerLink]=""  (click)='MostrarMapaFerias()'>Mapa de Férias</a>
```

=======

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuComponentComponent } from '../menu-component/menu-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-area-reservada-component',
  templateUrl: './area-reservada-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./area-reservada-component.component.css']
})
export class AreaReservadaComponentComponent implements  AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }

  @ViewChild(MenuComponentComponent) menu: MenuComponentComponent;
  public MapaFeriasIsVisible: boolean;
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

if (this.menu.MapaFeriasIsVisible) {
  this.MapaFeriasIsVisible = false;
} else {
  this.MapaFeriasIsVisible = true;
}

   }
}
```

===============================
MenuComponentComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-component',
  templateUrl: './menu-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-component.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponentComponent  {
  @Input() MapaFeriasIsVisible: boolean;
  constructor()
  {

  }


  public MostrarMapaFerias(): void
  {
    if (this.MapaFeriasIsVisible) {
      this.MapaFeriasIsVisible = false;
    } else {
      this.MapaFeriasIsVisible = true;
    }

  }

}
```

> O objectivo era mostrar e esconder quando é clicado no botão Mapa de
>   férias

Comment: Oi Amadeu, boa noite! Eu sugiro reescrever a questão de forma que fique mais fácil para beneficiar toda a comunidade. O problema `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` parece bem comum e uma resposta aqui ajudaria bastante... e para isso, só necessitaríamos que reestrutures a tua pergunta de forma que não pareça apenas que compartilhas teu código e esperas uma solução.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apesar de sua pergunta não ter sido muito clara, seria bom dar uma olhada na documentação oficial dos [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) do **Angular**, e [neste material](https://pt.slideshare.net/EyalV/component-lifecycle-hooks-in-angular-20) e este
[material aqui](https://code-examples.net/pt/docs/angular/guide/lifecycle-hooks) que também acho muito bom. Mas, resumindo e explicando um pouco até porque é bem complicado essa parte do Angular, o que acontece aí é que vc utilizando o lifecycle **`ngAfterViewInit()`** que age após as **views** do componente/diretiva ter sido inicializada o que busca por mudanças nos valores e consequentemente lança este erro, pois o Angular ainda não sabe qual o valor que deveria conter na diretiva e então para ele o valor mudou, como o próprio erro demonstra:

```
Expression has changed after it was checked.

A expressão mudou após ser verificada.
```

Apesar de este erro ocorrer apenas no ambiente de desenvolvimento vc pode resolve-lo da seguinte maneira, trocar o método:

> **ngAfterViewInit()**

por

> **ngAfterContentInit()**

Com o lifecycle `ngAfterContentInit()` basicamente primeiro será verificado se houve mudanças no conteúdo externo do componente e seus valores.